# Exact sequences in the Mumford example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, deformation-theory

This question concerns the proof for the Mumford example of an Hilbert Scheme that has a non-reduced component. I am studying the proof given on R. Hartshone, "Deformation Theory", pp. 91-94. I do not understand the following three facts.

(a) let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{3}$ be a nonsingular cubic surface, let $L$ be the sixth exceptional curve of $X$, and $H$ the hyperplane section of $X$. Consider an irreducible curve $C$ in the linear system $|4H+2L|$. Then the following sequence is exact:

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad
0\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(C) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C}(C) \longrightarrow 0
$

(b) with the same notation of (a), the following exact sequence of norml bundles is exact:

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad
0\longrightarrow \mathcal{N}_{C/X}\longrightarrow \mathcal{N}_{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}_{X}|_{C} \longrightarrow 0
$

(c) with the same notation of (a), the following sequence is exact:

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad 
0\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(2L-C)\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(2L) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C}(2L) \longrightarrow 0
$

I do not know if those questions can be written in more generic terms. Bibliographical references are also welcome.

Comment: Just a remark -- there is a harmless abuse of notation in these exact sequences that may be bugging you, namely, $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ is a sheaf on $C$, so it's grammatically incorrect to put it in an exact sequence of sheaves on $X$. (What's ``really meant'' is $i_* \mathcal{O}_C$ where $i$ is the inclusion of $C$ into $X$.) But from the perspective of cohomology, $i_*$ doesn't matter, so we usually write it this way in practice.

Comment: What on earth is "the sixth exceptional curve on $X$" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and last s.e.s. come from the sequence defining the structure sheaf of the curve $C$: $$0\to\mathcal I_C\to \mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_C\to 0,$$ and we use that $\mathcal I_C = \mathcal O_X(-C)$ to get $$0\to\mathcal O_X(-C)\to \mathcal O_X\to\mathcal O_C\to 0.$$ In the first case we twist everything by $C$ (i.e., do $-\otimes\mathcal O_X(C)$) and in the last case we twist everything by $2L$.

For the middle sequence, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94214/elementary-exact-sequence-of-normal-sheaves) is a related question, with an EGA reference for good measure.